# Error while using Dataframe Pivot table function

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to pivot my data frame on the basis of key value pair but getting the following error:

```
KeyError: 'reach_type'



During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)

/var/folders/3c/t0l0kcc54b1bh6jnftt11vn00000gn/T/ipykernel_3850/1768770531.py in <module>
      2 for x in mnth:
      3     pivot1 = rslt_df[rslt_df.activity_month_name == x].pivot_table(index=['hcp_mdm_id'], values=['reach'], aggfunc='sum')
----> 4     pivot1['reach_type'] = pivot1.apply(lambda row: reach(row), axis=1)
      5     rows.append([x,len(pivot1[pivot1['reach_type'].str.contains('reach1')]),len(pivot1[pivot1['reach_type'].str.contains('reach2')])])

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in __setitem__(self, key, value)
   3597             self._setitem_array(key, value)
   3598         elif isinstance(value, DataFrame):
-> 3599             self._set_item_frame_value(key, value)
   3600         elif is_list_like(value) and 1 < len(
   3601             self.columns.get_indexer_for([key])



ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 0, placement implies 1
```

In the code, I am trying to calculate the different reach and engage metric month over month for different channels for a particular person and name it as reach1 or reach2
Below is my code:

```
df['reach'] = df['aim_reached_flag'] + df['email_reached_flag'] + df['rep_reached_flag'] + df['sp_reached_flag'] + df['third_party_reached_flag'] + df['display_reached_flag']

df['engage'] = df['aim_engaged_flag'] + df['email_engaged_flag'] + df['rep_engaged_flag'] + df['sp_engaged_flag'] + df['third_party_engaged_flag'] + df['display_engaged_flag']

rslt_df = df[df['target_audience'] == 'Yes']

mnth = rslt_df.activity_month_name.unique()

def reach(row):
    if row['reach'] > 0 and row['reach'] < 100:
        reach_t = 'reach1'
    elif (row['reach'] > 99 and row['reach'] < 1000 and row['reach']%100 == 0):
        reach_t = 'reach1'
    elif (row['reach'] > 999 and row['reach'] < 10000 and row['reach']%1000 == 0):
        reach_t = 'reach1'
    elif (row['reach'] > 9999 and row['reach'] < 100000 and row['reach']%10000 == 0):
        reach_t = 'reach1'
    elif (row['reach'] > 99999 and row['reach'] < 1000000 and row['reach']%10000 == 0):
        reach_t = 'reach1'
    elif (row['reach'] > 999999 and row['reach'] < 10000000 and row['reach']%10000 == 0):
        reach_t = 'reach1'
    elif row['reach'] != 0:
        reach_t ='reach2'
    else:
        reach_t = 'not_reached'
    return reach_t

rows = []
for x in mnth:
    pivot1 = rslt_df[rslt_df.activity_month_name == x].pivot_table(index=['hcp_mdm_id'], values=['reach'], aggfunc='sum')
    pivot1['reach_type'] = pivot1.apply(lambda row: reach(row), axis=1)
    rows.append([x,len(pivot1[pivot1['reach_type'].str.contains('reach1')]),len(pivot1[pivot1['reach_type'].str.contains('reach2')])])
```

Print(result_df.head()) output :

```
  ser_no activity_date activiy_month activity_month_name activity_week  \
0      2    2020-08-01    2020-08-01         August-2020        Jul 27   
1      3    2020-08-01    2020-08-01         August-2020        Jul 27   
2      5    2020-08-01    2020-08-01         August-2020        Jul 27   
3      4    2020-08-01    2020-08-01         August-2020        Jul 27   
4      6    2020-08-01    2020-08-01         August-2020        Jul 27   

  hcp_mdm_id aim_engaged_flag aim_reached_flag email_engaged_flag  \
0   10528799                0                0                  0   
1   10472995                0                0                  0   
2   10639228                0                0                  0   
3   10386720                0                0                  0   
4   10857432                0                0                  0   

  email_reached_flag  ... rep_reached_flag sp_engaged_flag sp_reached_flag  \
0                  0  ...                0               0               0   
1                  0  ...                0               0               0   
2                  0  ...                0               0               0   
3                  0  ...                0               0               0   
4                  0  ...                0               0               0   

  third_party_engaged_flag third_party_reached_flag display_engaged_flag  \
0                        0                        0                    0   
1                        0                        0                    0   
2                        0                        0                    0   
3                        0                        0                    0   
4                        0                        0                    0   

  display_reached_flag target_audience    reach engage  
0                    0             Yes        0      0  
1              1000000             Yes  1000000      0  
2              1000000             Yes  1000000      0  
3                    0             Yes        0      0  
4              1000000             Yes  1000000      0
```

Comment: Error means there is no column `reach_type` in `pivot1`, hard to test without data. Can you add to question `print (rslt_df.head())` ?

Comment: @jezrael  I have done that

Answer (score 0):

Instead:

```
mnth = rslt_df.activity_month_name.unique()

rows = []
for x in mnth:
    pivot1 = rslt_df[rslt_df.activity_month_name == x].pivot_table(index=['hcp_mdm_id'], values=['reach'], aggfunc='sum')
    pivot1['reach_type'] = pivot1.apply(lambda row: reach(row), axis=1)
    rows.append([x,len(pivot1[pivot1['reach_type'].str.contains('reach1')]),len(pivot1[pivot1['reach_type'].str.contains('reach2')])])
```

First aggregate `sum` by `activity_month_name` and `hcp_mdm_id`, create new column and for counts use [`crosstab`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html):

```
pivot1 = rslt_df.groupby(['activity_month_name','hcp_mdm_id'])[['reach']].sum()

pivot1['reach_type'] = pivot1.apply(lambda row: reach(row), axis=1)

pivot1 = pivot1.reset_index()
new = (pd.crosstab(pivot1['activity_month_name'], 
                   pivot1['reach_type'])
         .reset_index()
         .rename_axis(index=None, columns=None))
```

Comment: I still get the same error using this

Comment: @slayer1996 - So is replaced solution? What is error?